# How to test all permutations of space-separated values in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, permutation

I need to incorporate all permutations when testing the possible values (separated by a space) for a variable in `xsl:when`.

For example:

```
<xsl:when test="$var='A B C' 
             or $var='B A C' 
             or $var='...' 
             or ...>
    <xsl:value-of select="X+Z"/>
```

Is there a smart and simple way of doing it?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I would prefer XSLT 1.0, if it is not possible, i can explore 2.0 option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to generate all permutations, I would test if all values of the source are present in the target, and that both source and target contain the same number of values.

This is a bit verbose in XSLT 1.0, but still:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>

<xsl:variable name="source" select="'A B C'"/>
<xsl:variable name="target" select="'B A C'"/>

<xsl:variable name="every-source-in-target">
    <xsl:call-template name="every-source-in-target">
        <xsl:with-param name="source" select="$source"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="target" select="$target"/>
    </xsl:call-template>        
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="count-source" select="string-length(translate($source, translate($source, $delimiter, ''), ''))" />
<xsl:variable name="count-target" select="string-length(translate($target, translate($target, $delimiter, ''), ''))" /> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:if test="$every-source-in-target='true' and $count-source=$count-target ">MATCH</xsl:if>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="every-source-in-target">
    <xsl:param name="source"/>
    <xsl:param name="target"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($source, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains(concat($delimiter, $target, $delimiter), concat($delimiter, $token, $delimiter)))">
            <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($source, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="every-source-in-target">
                <xsl:with-param name="source" select="substring-after($source, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="target" select="$target"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that some assumptions are being made here: for example, `"A B B C"` and `"B A A C"` will return a match. If that's not acceptable, then the next best thing, IMHO, would be to sort the values before comparing the sets:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>

<xsl:variable name="source" select="'A B C'"/>
<xsl:variable name="target" select="'B A C'"/>

<xsl:variable name="sorted-source">
    <xsl:call-template name="sort-list">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$source"/>
    </xsl:call-template>        
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="sorted-target">
    <xsl:call-template name="sort-list">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$target"/>
    </xsl:call-template>        
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:if test="$sorted-source=$sorted-target">MATCH</xsl:if>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sort-list">
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
    <!-- tokenize the list -->
    <xsl:variable name="tokens">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$list"/>
        </xsl:call-template>        
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- re-assemble the list in alphabetic order -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($tokens)/token">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <token>
                <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
            </token>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

> An efficient solution for verifying that a single string is an exact
>   permutation of a given set of strings is presented here:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/35497256/36305

**The following verifies that the children of the top element of the source XML document are *all* possible permutations of a given set of strings**.

Rules:

1. A single space must be used as delimiter.
2. Any string in the given string-set doesn't contain a space.
3. The value of any child of the top element of the XML document must be a normalized string -- should only contain inner single spaces, each delimiting two adjacent non-space-containing substrings.

The transformation produces the string "*Valid input.*" if the string values of `/*/*` (the children of the top element of the XML document) represent every possible permutation of the items of the given string-set -- and exactly once.

If this is not so, the transformation terminates with diagnostic messages explaining the exact violation found.

The items of the string-set are represented as children of an XML element that is the value of the global parameter, named *prtfData*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="prtfData">
   <v>A</v>
   <v>B</v>
   <v>C</v>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vData" select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name = 'prtfData']/*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vnumItems" select="count($vData)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vTotalLength" select="string-length($prtfData) + $vnumItems -1"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vnumPermutations">
   <xsl:call-template name="factorial">
     <xsl:with-param name="pN" select="$vnumItems"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:if test="not(count(*) = $vnumPermutations)">
      <xsl:message terminate="yes">
         Error: The count of /*/* is not <xsl:value-of select="$vnumPermutations"/>
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="v[not(string-length() = $vTotalLength)]">
      <xsl:message terminate="yes">
         The input item "<xsl:value-of select="v[not(string-length() = $vTotalLength)]"/>" <xsl:text/>
         <xsl:text/>has string-length not-equal to <xsl:text/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$vTotalLength"/>
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:variable name="vInput" select="/*/*"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$vData">
      <xsl:variable name="vPaddedItem" select="concat(' ', ., ' ')"/>
      <xsl:if test="$vInput[not(contains(concat(' ', ., ' '), $vPaddedItem))]">
          <xsl:message terminate="yes">
             Error: The data item "<xsl:value-of select="."/>" isn't contained in <xsl:text/>
             <xsl:value-of select="$vInput[not(contains(concat(' ', ., ' '), $vPaddedItem))]"/>.
          </xsl:message>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:if test="$vInput[. = preceding-sibling::* or . = following-sibling::*]">
          <xsl:message terminate="yes">
             Error: Some data items are equal. Not all permutations represented.
          </xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>

    Valid input.
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="factorial">
    <xsl:param name="pN" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="pResult" select="1"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($pN > 0)">
          <xsl:value-of select="$pResult"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="factorial">
            <xsl:with-param name="pN" select="$pN -1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pResult" select="$pN * $pResult"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
  <v>C B A</v>
  <v>C A B</v>
  <v>B A C</v>
  <v>B C A</v>
  <v>A C B</v>
  <v>A B C</v>
</t>
```

**the result is**:

> Valid input.

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <v>C B A</v>
  <v> C A B </v>
  <v>B A C</v>
  <v>B C A</v>
  <v>A C B</v>
  <v>A B C</v>
</t>
```

**the processing is terminated with this message**:

> The input item " C A B " has string-length not-equal to 5

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <v>C B A</v>
  <v>C C B</v>
  <v>B A C</v>
  <v>B C A</v>
  <v>A C B</v>
  <v>A B C</v>
</t>
```

**the processing is terminated with this message**:

> Error: The data item "A" isn't contained in C C B.

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <v>C B A</v>
  <v>C C B</v>
  <v>B A C</v>
</t>
```

**the processing is terminated with this message**:

> Error: The count of `/*/*` is not 6

**Finally, when the transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <v>C B A</v>
  <v>C A B</v>
  <v>C A B</v>
  <v>B A C</v>
  <v>A C B</v>
  <v>A B C</v>
</t>
```

**the processing is terminated with this message**:

> Error: Some data items are equal. Not all permutations represented.

Comment: This solution seems very expensive. Surely a solution that sorts both sequences and compares the result item-by-item would be a lot more efficient? Also, I don't think use of `document("")` should be encouraged. It assumes an interpreted environment where the source code of the stylesheet is available at run-time, and that's not always going to be the case.

Comment: @MichaelKay, If we have to verify n! strings, this will always be at least O(n!) -- even if a hash-table is used. With sorting the values and using binary search, we will need O(n! * log(n!)) just for the sorting, then using binary search will be O(log(n!). So, I fully agree that **any** such validation is obviously inefficient. Possibly we have different understanding about what the OP wants. Mine is that he wants to verify that a set of strings contains exactly all permutations (each string representing one permutation, of a predefined set of strings.

Comment: My interpretation of the question was "I want to test whether $var contains the tokens "A B C" in some permutation". That is, `deep-equal(tokenize($var) => sort(), tokenize("A B C") => sort())`

Comment: @MichaelKay, Yes, for that interpretation this is a suitable way. I think using keys (such as `every $t in tokenize($var) satisfies key('kn', $var, $stylesheetDoc)` can be O(N), while the sorting solution is O(N*log(N)). Here we have 'A', 'B' and 'C' as the string values of a nodes in a tree -- it is possible even to pass this tree as a parameter.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I see that what I proposed in the previous comment will not detest having repetitions of strings. I created another answer, which uses all permutations as key values. This is practical for not more than 7-8 different strings and is conveniently expressed in XSLT 1.0

Comment: @MichaelKay, My 2nd (last, just edited) answer is in XSLT 2.0, avoids sorting and avoids enumeration of all permutations. I believe, that it is generic and also more efficient (`O(N)`) than a solution that sorts the tokens (`O(N * log(N)`).

Comment: isn't the cost of `test="$vInput[. = preceding-sibling::* or . = following-sibling::*]"` likely to be quadratic in the size of $vInput, unless somehow optimised?

Comment: @MichaelKay, I am not using anything like this in my answer ?!? You are looking at the earlier answer that verifies a set of input data -- not just a single row, The efficient solution is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35497256/36305

Answer (score 1):

If all the strings are valid names, then a neat 2.0 solution would be to turn the strings into attributes and use deep-equals():

```
deep-equal(f:to-atts(source), f:to-atts(target))

<xsl:function f:to-atts as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string">
  <e>
   <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($in, ' ')">
     <xsl:attribute name="." select="0"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </e>
</xsl:function>
```

Note this eliminates duplicates: "A A" will be equal to "A". You haven't said whether this is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

The quick & easy way of doing this is to first define a variable that puts your delimiter at the beginning and end like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="tempVar" select="concat(' ',$var,' ')"/>
```

then simply use

```
<xsl:when test="contains($tempVar,' A ') and
                contains($tempVar, ' B ') and
                contains($tempVar, ' C ')">
  <xsl:value-of select="X+Z"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Putting a space at the beginning & end of `tempVar` just means that all values are surrounded by spaces whether at the beginning/end or not, making it possible to just check for the presence of each value with a space at each side.

You could do without the variable of course, you'd just need to repeat the concat expression three times in your `test` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**An XSLT 2.0 solution that avoids sorting and is more efficient: `O(N)` vs. `O(N*log(N))`**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:key name="kAllItems" match="x" use="."/>

  <xsl:param name="pData">
   <x>A</x>
   <x>B</x>
   <x>C</x>
 </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="v">
    (<xsl:value-of select="."/>) ==> <xsl:sequence 
                                          select="my:exactPremutation(., $pData)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:exactPremutation" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="pInput" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="pDataItems" as="document-node()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNumDataItems" select="count($pDataItems/*)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vMatches" as="xs:integer*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize($pInput, '\s+')" group-by=".">
        <xsl:variable name="vMatchedDataItem" 
                      select="key('kAllItems', current-grouping-key(), $pDataItems)"/>

          <xsl:sequence select="1[not(current-group()[2]) and $vMatchedDataItem]"/>
          <xsl:sequence select="($vNumDataItems +1)[not($vMatchedDataItem)]"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:sequence select="sum($vMatches) eq $vNumDataItems"/>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
  <!-- Correct -->
   <v>A B C</v>
   <v>A C B</v>
   <v>B A C</v>
   <v>B C A</v>
   <v>C A B</v>
   <v>C B A</v>
  <!-- Incorrect -->
   <v>C A C</v>
   <v>A B</v>
   <v></v>
   <v>A B C D</v>   
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

> ```
> (A B C) ==> true
>
> (A C B) ==> true
>
> (B A C) ==> true
>
> (B C A) ==> true
>
> (C A B) ==> true
>
> (C B A) ==> true
>
>
> (C A C) ==> false
>
> (A B) ==> false
>
> () ==> false
>
> (A B C D) ==> false
> ```

**Note**: The linear efficiency estimation assumes that an efficient (such as hash-table based) implementation of grouping is used by the XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple XPath 1.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="x" select="'B A C'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="y" select="'A B C'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($x) = string-length($y)
                      and translate($x, $y, '') = ''">
        <xsl:message>Same</xsl:message>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message>Different</xsl:message>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes unique, single-char values being permuted.